# Android - How to send and receive nested parceled objects "Bundles"

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send and receive a parceled array object within another parceled object through bundles.

Always, Having issues with Array lengths

CODE : PARCELED ARRAY OBJECTS Author.java

```
public class Author implements Parcelable {

public String firstName;
public String middleInitial;
public String lastName;

public Author() {
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(this.firstName);
    out.writeString(this.middleInitial);
    out.writeString(this.lastName);
}

private Author(Parcel in) {  
    this.firstName = in.readString();
    this.middleInitial = in.readString();
    this.lastName = in.readString();
}

public int describeContents(){
    return  0;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Author> CREATOR  = new Parcelable.Creator<Author>() {
    @Override
    public Author createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Author(in);
    }
    @Override
    public Author[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Author[size];
    }
};

public String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if (firstName != null && !"".equals(firstName)) {
        sb.append(firstName);
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    if (middleInitial != null && !"".equals(middleInitial)) {
        sb.append(middleInitial);
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    if (lastName != null && !"".equals(lastName)) {
        sb.append(lastName);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

CODE : PARCELED BOOK OBJECT Book.java

```
public class Book implements Parcelable {

public int id;  
public String title;
public Author[] authors;
public String isbn;
public String price;

private Book(Parcel in) {  
    this.id = in.readInt();
    this.title = in.readString();
    in.readTypedArray(authors, Author.CREATOR);
    this.isbn = in.readString();
    this.price = in.readString();
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeInt(this.id);
    out.writeString(this.title);
    out.writeArray(this.authors);
    out.writeString(this.isbn);
    out.writeString(this.price);
}

public int describeContents(){
    return  0;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Book> CREATOR  = new Parcelable.Creator<Book>() {
    @Override
    public Book createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Book(in);
    }
    @Override
    public Book[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Book[size];
    }
};

public Book(int id, String title, Author[] author, String isbn, String price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.authors = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

Call and Create objects :

```
Book new_book =  new Book(1, title, authors.parseAuthors(author), isbn, "35$");
Intent i = new Intent(this, BookActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("key", new_book);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Remote Activity "BOOK ACTIVITY.CLASS"

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Book book = bundle.getParcelable("key");
```

Any ideas, how can i fix this issue.? NESTED PARCELED WITHIN BUNDLES. Also, I am sure if i am using the right way to read array in parcelable on author object.

Thanks,

Comment: I have changed this "out.writeArray()" to "out.writeTypedArray()" as well. I got it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Parcel.createTypedArray(ClassLoader...) instead.  From what I'm seeing, you're using readTypedArray, but not initializing the destination array before trying to read into it.  In order to do it that way, you'd need to pass the current length of the array through the Parcel, and initialize the array at the correct size before reading into it.

Comment: I tried to use createTypedArray  "this.authors=in.createTypedArray(Author.CREATOR); but the reasults that i was expecting are wrong .. "authors names start shifting into another variable".